# How do I pass the this context into an event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I know this question doesn't make much sense, but let me try and clarify a bit.

I have a class, called `ScrollBanner`, and it looks somewhat as follows (a lot omitted for brevity):

```
function ScrollBanner() {
    this.initialize = function(selector) {
        $('span#banner1-nav').click(this._onClickNavigation);
    }

    this._onClickNavigation = function(event) {
        this.restartTimer(); // this == span#banner1-nav element from this.initialize
        //...
    }

    this.restartTimer() {
        //...
    }
}
```

As you can see `this.initialize` sets a click handler to `this._onClickNavigation`. Some might expect the `this` inside the event handler to refer to the `ScrollBanner` instance, but sadly it doesn't. It refers to the element that triggered the click event, in this case `span#banner1-nav`.

What would be the best way to get `this` to refer to the `ScrollBanner` class instance?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**The old/traditional way:**

Capture `this` in a variable:

```
this.initialize = function(selector) {
    var that = this;
    $('span#banner1-nav').click(function(event) {
       that._onClickNavigation(event);
    });
}
```

You could also assign `this` to a variable e.g. `instance`:

```
function ScrollBanner() {
    var instance = this;
    // ...
}
```

and refer to `instance` instead of `this` in all the calls.

The overall idea is to store `this` in a variable in a higher scope.

---

**The ECMAScript5 way:**

ECMAScript5 introduces a new property of functions: [`.bind()`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.4.5). [MDC's documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) shows an implementation for browsers that don't support it. With it you can bind a certain context to a function:

```
this.initialize = function(selector) {
    $('span#banner1-nav').click(this._onClickNavigation.bind(this));
}
```

but behind the scenes it is doing the same thing. The advantage is that you make use of built-in functionality in browser that support is.

Note that this is different from [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call). Both of these set the context **and** execute the function, whereas `bind` only sets the context without executing the function.

---

**The jQuery way:**

jQuery provides a method [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that is doing the same:

```
$('span#banner1-nav').click($.proxy(this._onClickNavigation, this));
```

Comment: Good call, I generally make a habit of assigning a `var that = this` at the top of my constructors so you always have a reference to it. Then use `that` all the time just so there is no confusion (assuming of course you're referencing that, and not some other this)

Comment: This is quite useful but it feels quite dirty. :)

Comment: @JoeZephyr: That's the way it is ;) Please have a look at my update too.

Comment: Doesn't jQuery have a bind() function that is cross browser compatible?

Comment: @JoeZephyr: Right, I forgot. jQuer has `$.proxy`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/ At least you know all possible ways now ;)

Comment: I wish people would stop call the this keyword "context". It isn't. The (unspecified) term "context" might describe scope, but it has nothing to do with what a function's this keyword references.

Comment: @RobG each function has a context, a `function context`, that's always reffered to by using the `this` keyword.

Comment: @ahmehri—ECMA-262 defines what ["*function context*"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4) is. *this* is a parameter of a function's execution context, it isn't *the* context.

Comment: In es2015 classes every internal function is accessed with `this.functionName()`. Which results and the need to bind every single DOM event handler. We need global "class" properties that can be accessed without "this" and then we could use "that" or "self" all the time instead. I'm open to suggestions, as migrating dom module code to the "class" way is almost counter productive.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I saw, that in the comments, $.proxy() is mentioned. Yes, it does change the context of an object but not in an jQuery event.

```
 $('.selector').click( $.proxy( function() {
     console.log(this); /* this is set to .selector */
 }, this));
```

$.proxy() returns the function in the scope that `this` reffered but then that function is returned and used by `click()` which then changes the scope to `.selector` element.

I've tested it a minute ago but if i got it wrong, please, do tell

Comment: Not sure if this was different in older jQuery versions, but this example shows that you are wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/mazztgc9/.