# Javascript onclick event call object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass the this context into an event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490448/how-do-i-pass-the-this-context-into-an-event-handler)

I am doing a Javascript related assignment and am required to make a calendar which is associated with a particular input.

The calendar is displayed constantly and does not hide, etc.

There can be multiple calendars pointing to different text fields.

Now, each calendar is created by a Javascript object, i.e.

```
var cal1=new Calendar("inputfield_id");
```

Now the calendar object has certain variables that I want to access when the calendar is clicked on.

So basically, my question is, is there a way to get a particular object for an onclick event, i.e. somehow getting the "this" variable when you are in an object.

---

Here's a small portion of the code to explain what I am trying to do:

```
function calendar(id){
   this.date=new Date();
   this.id=id;
   this.next_year=function(){
        this.date.setFullYear(this.date.getFullYear()+1);
        alert(this.date); // basically I want to get object context here to change date
   }

   var temp_but=document.createElement("button").onclick=this.next_year;
   document.getElementById(id+"_div").appendChild(temp_but);
   document.getElementById(id+"_div").lastChild.onclick=this.next_year;

}
```

basically, in `this.nextyear` function, I want to get object context to get date and change calendar accordingly.

Comment: no, cant use jquery. only javascript

Comment: If `Calendar` has a property `id` you can access it like `cal1.id`. `this` is `cal1`

Comment: Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate us the Calendar constructor and how you call it?

Comment: Calendar is not a native DOM api. What are you using?

Comment: Do you mean srcElement/target ?

Comment: its declared right under it. look at calendar function. I basically want to replace the "this" in the next_year function with a variable pointing to a particular object context.

Comment: Your question seems confusing, I still don't get it... If what you want to do is change the context of `this` you can use `call` or `apply`, is that what you mean?

Comment: Hmm, yes something like that, but I how will I use it to point to a particular object?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking to do...

```
function calendar(id){
   this.date=new Date();
   this.id=id;
   var context = this;
   this.next_year=function(){
        context.date.setFullYear(context.date.getFullYear()+1);
        alert(context.date);//basically i want to get object context here to change date
   }

   var temp_but=document.createElement("button").onclick=this.next_year;
   document.getElementById(id+"_div").appendChild(temp_but);
   document.getElementById(id+"_div").lastChild.onclick=this.next_year;

}
```

Essentially, we're using a closure to preserve a reference to `this` called `context`. `this.next_year` now has a reference to the calendar object via `context`.

---

EDIT: a little JS lesson in response to the comment OP posted.

---

When you call a function as a constructor (i.e. **`new`** `calendar("example")`), a new empty object is created and the function is executed in the context of the new empty object.

note: It's not really *just* an empty object. It's an empty object with certain internal pointers behind the scenes for things like prototypal inheritance.

Anywho! Throughout a function, any reference to this refers to the current context. And, because when you use a function as a constructor, it calls the function in the context of a newly created object, you can set properties of the object using `this.someProperty`.

When you execute the statement `var cal1=new calendar("inputfield_id");`, a new object is created, and your function `calendar` gets executed in the context of said object. So, `this.date=new Date();` and `this.id=id` are setting the `date` and `id` properties of your new calendar object.

I'm assuming you aren't actually having trouble understanding what happens here: `this.id=id;` but rather why the `this` keyword wasn't working in `this.next_year`.

Let's start off with a scenario where it would have works. If you were to call `cal1.next_year();`, you'd be calling `next_year()` in the context of `cal1`, so `this.date.setFullYear(this.date.getFullYear()+1);` would increment `cal1`'s date property by 1 year as expected.

It wasn't working at the click event handler because when you set the event handler, you're kind of saying "when the 'click' event is fired, execute this **function**" as opposed to "when the 'click' event is fired, execute this **statement**".

the function that's actually executing being:

```
   function(){
        this.date.setFullYear(this.date.getFullYear()+1);
        alert(this.date);
   }
```

and the statement you were expecting to execute being:

```
   this.next_year(); //where this refers to the calendar object.
```

---

When this code is executing,

```
elem.onclick = this.next_year;
```

it's the same as saying,

```
elem.onclick = function(){
    this.date.setFullYear(this.date.getFullYear()+1);
    alert(this.date);
}
```

So, if this doesn't make the issue clear enough, let me go a little further and explain what actually happens when an element, `elem`, is clicked after a click handler was set using `elem.onclick=this.next_year;`. I like to think of it as though the browser is calling `elem.onclick([Event event]);`. Essentially, the function you set using `elem.onclick=` is executed in the context of `elem` and an `Event` object is passed in as the first and only argument.

To be blatantly clear and drive the point home, the `this` keyword in your function points to the element that was clicked when it's invoked by the browser as an event handler.

```
   function(){
        this.date.setFullYear(this.date.getFullYear()+1);
        alert(this.date);
   }
```

---

I apologize for over-explaining and being repetitive/redundant. I try to keep my answers short because I'm generally bad at explaining things :P

PS - don't forget to accept!

Comment: Thanks man, exactly what I was looking for! but,I am still a little confused as to how this is working. "this.id=id", what exactly happens here?