# Call a property object function with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS looks like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
itemOptions["_myStuff"] = {
  first: "some_variable",
  second: "another_variable",

  getSomeValue: function(asd){
    ...
  },

  doSomething: function(){
    ...
  }
}
some other JS stuff
</script>
```

And then, inside the functions, if I want to call another function that is a property of this `itemOptions["_myStuff"]`, then I do this: `itemOptions["_myStuff"].doSomething();`

It's all good in the hood, but now I need to call a function upon `onclick` and it doesn't work the way I want it. It looks like that:

```
... onclick="itemOptions["_myStuff"].getSomeValue(\'' asd '\'); ...">
```

I tried escaping the quotation marks around `itemOptions` or `_myStuff` but no success. Any ideas how to approach this?

P.S. The code has been given to me in this format, and I am just working on top of it, so I don't know why it has been made this way.

Comment: Try attaching your events _in JavaScript_ to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Possible for Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879809/javascript-onclick-event-call-object,

Comment: @elclanrs - but the HTML code for the element, that contains the `onclick=...` is created on the fly, under certain circumstances, so if I attach an event to it, the event is gonna be attached to nothing, because the buttons won't be created yet.

Comment: Event delegation is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would solve this just by correct escaping. Try this:

```
... onclick="itemOptions[\'_myStuff\'].getSomeValue(...">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes inside a double-quoted string. Try this:

```
onclick="itemOptions['_myStuff'].getSomeValue(' asd ')";
```

Comment: You are missing closing quotes